# Issues Installing Simfinger Application

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm trying to install the [SimFinger application](https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger) for doing a screencast with my iOS Simulator.

When I download the project from Github or get the files from the [only other location I've found them available for download online](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/SimFinger.shtml) I simply get a `.tar.gz` file that uncompresses into a collection of files that I have no idea what to do with.

How can I get a `.app` file out of these files that I can install in my `Applications` folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open IOS simulator
2. In finder: Navigate go to atebits-SimFinger-.../Fake/Simfinger and open FakeFinger.xcodeproj
3. Run it (press "play" in xcode)